# I am unable to change the Admin URL for magento 2. The URL is still redirecting to old site

Tags: magento2

the magento admin URL  site keeps redirecting to the old site URL.

I have used every converstional method to change the URL but its still redirecting.

I.e

I change the url in my env.php i cleaned my cache.
I tried setting  it by command line : setup:config:set --backend-frontname="admin"

Each time I did the following:

```
maintenance:enable

 setup:upgrade;
 setup:static-content:deploy -f;
 setup:di:compile;
 maintenance:disable;
 index:reindex;
 cache:flush;
 cleared the cache,
```

I even  inserted the new name into database table:

i.e

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data`(`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
VALUES(
'default', # Or whatever your Scope is
0, # Or whatever your Scope ID is
'admin/url/custom',
'https://mysite.test/admin/'
);
```

any ideas where it might be set?

Comment: try to remove first **`var/cache`** and **`var/view_preprocessed`**.and last above commands run.

Comment: hey @MohitPatel. tried it. no luck.